# Why is the current wrong after resistors in series with simple LED?

Tags: led, resistors, current-limiting, constant-current, testing

**Setup**

- source --- 1.5V batteries x2 = 3V
- LED --- 2V 35mA http://www.futurlec.com/LED/LED5R.shtml
- Resistors --- CR1W 1W 10ohm +-5%  x 4 = 40ohm

**Description**

I have your average "Light up a LED" experiment. I have a 3V source(worn out to 2.72 now) followed by 4x 10ohm resistors and a 2V 35mA LED.

**Problem**

3V... need to drop that 1V on the resistors and the current below 35mA... LED lights up but the reading is wrong! I get 2.08V after resistors which is good. But my current reading after resistors reads 58mA. Since current in series is said to be same for all circuit, it was supposed to be 1V/40ohm = 0.025A = 25mA(worn out now, so: 0.66/40 ~= 16mA). Why on earth is it 58mA?

I have tested the resistance between source and before LED(right after resistors), reads 40ohm.

Any ideas? I'm lost :(

Comment: Your probably measuring the current wrong. Are you placing the meter in series, with the resistors and led?

Comment: if mA and V readings vs Ohm readings don't match, it's measurement errror.

Comment: If @Passerby is correct in his or her guess, you are very close to blowing the fuse in your multimeter. Stop and read about current measurement before proceeding. It's no fun to have to go looking for a replacement of the correct type and rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably measuring the current wrong. Are you placing the meter in series, with the resistors and led?

If you are only measuring the current across the resistors, 2.7V across 40 ohms = 68 milliamps. But then you have to take into account that the battery has a high Equivalent Series Resistance. As the current rises, the voltage drops across the ESR, leading to a lower battery voltage, etc etc. That's the most possible situation.

You have to measure the current with the multimeter in series with the battery, resistors, and led.

Comment: Thanks a lot! a common mistake in a common experiment. Now it's showing 17mA. still not the 0.29mA you'd expect from 30ohm(removed one resistor). I'm guessing the rest is due to how you mentioned battery resistance? I thought the batteries(2x = 2.87V) doesn't resist as much.

Comment: @infogeek I assumed you were using country cells. If you're using AA or AAA it doesn't apply. But that led is more likely 20 mA at 2.0V or so. The 35 mA is a max limit.